# Can we execute batch files sequentially using single processpanel in izpack

Tags: java, izpack

i have created installer using izpack 4.3.5.I want to run the batch files sequentially one after another.

here is my processSpec.xml

```
<job name="buildCCE">
    <executefile name="bin\build.bat">
    <arg>deploy1.xml</arg>
    </executefile>
  </job>
<job name="buildCCE">
    <executefile name="bin\build2.bat">
    <arg>deploy2.xml</arg>
    </executefile>
  </job>
<job name="buildCCE">
    <executefile name="bin\build3.bat">
    <arg>deploy3.xml</arg>
    </executefile>
  </job>
```

is it possible to execute batch files sequentially using izpack with single process panel.
if not could you let me know how we can achieve this?

Comment: Can you show your build.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single `doWork.bat` file that `CALL`s the other batch files in the desired order:

```
REM Master batch file

ECHO Running first job...
CALL bin\build.bat

ECHO Running second job...
CALL bin\build2.bat

...

ECHO Running nth job...
CALL bin\buildn.bat
```